# AWS Cli: Invalid Method identifier specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

So I am trying to invoke our backend's API through AWS cli as it is shown in documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/test-invoke-method.html):

```
# exalmple from the docs:
# aws apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id 1234123412 --resource-id avl5sg8fw8 --http-method GET --path-with-query-string '/'

# my own call
aws apigateway test-invoke-method --rest-api-id ${restId} --resource-id ${resID} --http-method GET --path-with-query-string '/health'
```

However, it fails with :

```
An error occurred (NotFoundException) when calling the TestInvokeMethod operation: Invalid Method identifier specified
```

The error message is confusing and makes me think I don't know how to spell `GET`. Any help with what's wrong?

Version

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.15.15 Python/3.11.6 Darwin/23.3.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

Comment: Can you show your `restId`?

Comment: I don't know, can I ? I know it is correct because `aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id ${restID}` returns me a response with all routes listed. I copied it from AWS web interface. EDIT: it looks like `cu5lp25jk2`, i changed couple of letters

Comment: Is it typo here? `--resource-id ${resID}`

Comment: @ArpitJain if you are talking about uppercase/lowercase `resID`, then no, it's not a typo

Comment: Are you sure the resource has the method `GET`? Can you share the output of `aws apigateway get-resources --rest-api-id ${restID} --region<your_region>`? Also, can you try with `--debug` mode if that gives you more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey I misunderstood what `resource-id` supposed to mean. I thought it identifies the whole API, and then I pass some route "/route" to call.

In fact, it identifies a single route, and this particular route which I was calling didn't have any http methods associated. So i need to use the resource-id of the *route* i want to invoke